# USB Debugging option on my Android keeps turning off [Huawei]

Tags: android, debugging, huawei-mobile-services, usb-debugging

I was trying to connect my android device to my laptop to open a screen mirroring software and i enconterd a problem, every time i turn the USB debugging on and close the developer menu whene i go back into the menu the USB debugging option is turned off automaticly.

I have tried to revoke all USB debugging authorization and even Restore the default settings but that didn’t work for me. I expected to work after all I’m resting everything. any suggestions?

Comment: What Huawei phone and screen mirroring software do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. First of all, We need to turn on developer mode.

1. Go to "Settings"
2. Tap "About device" or "About phone"
3. Tap "Build number" several times
4. Enter your password and now you can see "Developer Settings" on your Settings menu.

Then, We need to make some settings on your "Developer Settings"

1. Go to "Settings" and tap "System&Updates"
2. Tap "Developer Options"
3. Scroll down until see "Debugging"
4. Open "Always prompt when connecting to USB"
5. Close "Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode"
6. Scroll down until see "Networking"
7. Tap "Select USB configuration"
8. Select "Media Transfer Protocol(MTP)

I hope this will help your problem.